# 2 way communication using webrtc?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webrtc

I'm trying to learn how to use webrtc to allow users to have a 2 way communication via webcam and audio.

I have come across this: [LINK](http://www.silvawood.co.uk/tutorial/index.htm)

Which i thought was perfect for me to start learning as it seems quite simple and straight to the point unlike other stuff that I found on google.

however, I really cannot make this work on their own demo and on my own server!

I only get my own webcam view in a small window and I cannot find any links to share with someone else!

I thought this: `<a id="link" target="_blank">Video Link</a>` would be the link to share the chat session with someone else but there is absolutely nothing happening when i click on that link.

the main reason I've chosen to use the code shown in the link above was because it doesn't seem to be using any plugins unlike others.

the question that i have is that am I missing something to make this work?

or Do I need a `plugin` to make `webrtc` to work for video/audio P2P chat?

any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/mgiuliani/webrtc-video-chat and demo: http://mg-webrtc.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @Alex, what programming language is that written in?

Comment: it's C# using SignalR for connection: http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/48/Peer-to-Peer-Media-Streaming-with-WebRTC-and-SignalR.aspx

Sorry, I didn't understand you want to use just html5 without server side.

Comment: @Alex, no, I want to use server side too but NOT C# or C++. That is not my thing. I use PHP/MYSQL and that link i posted is PHP/MYSQL as well. I have no idea where to start with C#.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using PHP for webrtc signaling.  You'll want something a little more web socket friendly.  How well do you know javascript?  Most small to medium sized webrtc projects use node.js where you use javascript for the client AND server.   http://peerjs.com/ is a good open source starting point.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is used for P2P communication by its nature and I would recommend to use something simple like http://simplewebrtc.com/

See code below which you can use to create simple WebRTC application, just change room name from testing123 to something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://simplewebrtc.com/latest.js"></script> 
        <style>
            #remoteVideos video {
                height: 320px;
            }
            #localVideo {
                height: 240px;
            }
        </style>
<script>
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
    remoteVideosEl: 'remoteVideos',
    // immediately ask for camera access
    autoRequestMedia: true,
//    url: 'atlas'
});

// we have to wait until it's ready
webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
    // you can name it anything
    webrtc.joinRoom('testing123');
});

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="localVideo"></video>
        <div id="remoteVideos"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin. You need to be able to write javascript to work with the WebRTC API in the browser (It doesn't sound like you want to write your own native application?), and you need some sort of signalling server to enable two peers (browser clients) to send messages to each other. You don't necessarily need a database, depending on your needs.